# How do I prove that for an elliptic curve the only isomorphism is the following way?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I habe an elliptic curve over a field $K$ given by:

$$E: y^2=x^3+Ax+B$$

Now I want to show that all changes of variables preserving this form are given by $x=u^2x$ and $y=u^3y$ with $u \in \bar{K}^*$...
Any idea how to show it?

Comment: $u^3y$ instead of $y^3y$?

Comment: Of course, sorry

Comment: You know how all the possible changing of variables look like. You can find this in the beginning of Chapter 3 of Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves...

Comment: I have the book but I can't find a proof why this is the only possible change of variables?